# Where does a tuple store its data?

Tags: c++, tuples

When I define a tuple like `std::tuple<int, char> foo;` Where inside the class does it store the `int` and `char` values? I'm looking for a layman's terms explanation.

Comment: Its implementation specific. Step into your `<tuple>` and find out. In every case I've ever seen they're done via variadic expansion with one member/type/index trio per expansion level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the time to digest it then the [GNU implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a01066_source.html) is actually a decent example of recursive inheritance using C++0x variadic templates. This is not a subject that lends itself easily to a layman's explanation and is best understood by reading the code over and over until it makes sense.

From what I can see they're inheriting upwards for each successive type in the tuple's type-list with each inherited class taking charge of the storage for that type until the recursion hits the end of the type-list.

Comment: Recursive inheritance was the answer to my question! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere it wants, really. I mean, it's an implementation detail. But I would say all implementations will eventually boil down to data members with automatic storage duration inside the tuple object. If you're really interested, you can look into the source code of open-source standard library implementations (like [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) and [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/)) or the implementation used by your compiler.